# How do i get 2 TextInput values through the id

Tags: python, kivy

So i have the class which has to create task and it looks like this

```
class CreateTask(Screen):
    def CreateTask(self,*args):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",spacing=10)
        name=self.root.ids.TaskName.text
        desc=self.root.ids.TaskDesc.text
        bl.add_widget(name)
        bl.add_widget(desc)
        self.root.MainLayout.add_widget(bl)
```

but i get the error  'CreateTask' object has no attribute 'root', so how do i get the text from 2 TextInputs through the id?

and here is my kv code for that class

```
<CreateTask>
    name:"third"
    AnchorLayout:
        size:root.size
        anchor_x:"center"
        anchor_y:"top"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            size_hint:[0.6,0.6]
            Label:
                text:"Input Task Name"
            TextInput:
                size_hint:[0.2,0.2]
                id:"TaskName"
            TextInput:
                size_hint:[0.6,0.6]
                id:"TaskDesc"
                multiline:False
            Button:
                size_hint:[0.4,0.4]
                text:"come_back"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current ="second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            Button:
                size_hint:[0.4,0.4] 
                text:"Create"
                on_release:root.CreateTask(*args)
```

here is the MainLayout

```
BoxLayout:
            size_hint:[0.4,0.2]
            id:MainLayout
            orientation:"vertical"
            Button:
                size_hint:[0.3,0.3]
                text:"Add Task"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current="third"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

also it looks like there is an error with tabulation, there is not, it's just pasted like that

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'CreateTask' object has no attribute 'root' because 'self' is already the root. And do not use string as id.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class CreateTask(Screen):
    def CreateTask(self, *args):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",spacing=10)
        name=self.ids.TaskName.text
        desc=self.ids.TaskDesc.text
        lbl_name = Label(text=name)
        lbl_desc = Label(text=desc)
        bl.add_widget(lbl_name)
        bl.add_widget(lbl_desc)
        self.ids.MainLayout.add_widget(bl)

sm = ScreenManager()
Builder.load_file("mainscreen.kv")
sm.add_widget(CreateTask())

class MainScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainScreenApp().run()
```

```
<CreateTask>
    name:"third"
    AnchorLayout:
        size:root.size
        anchor_x:"center"
        anchor_y:"top"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            size_hint:[0.6,0.6]
            Label:
                text:"Input Task Name"
            TextInput:
                size_hint:[0.2,0.2]
                id: TaskName
            TextInput:
                size_hint:[0.6,0.6]
                id: TaskDesc
                multiline:False
            Button:
                size_hint:[0.4,0.4]
                text:"come_back"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current: "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction: "left"
            Button:
                size_hint:[0.4,0.4]
                text:"Create"
                on_release: root.CreateTask(*args)

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:[0.4,0.2]
        id:MainLayout
        orientation:"vertical"
        Button:
            size_hint:[0.3,0.3]
            text:"Add Task"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="third"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: yes, it does fix the problem, but now i get  AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'  which  refer to self.ids.MainLayout.add_widget(bl). Is there any other way to get boxlayout object through the id and add new elements to it?

Comment: Did you change id:"TaskName" to id:TaskName ?

Comment: yes i did, and i changed every id from string to normal look

Comment: What is MainLayout? You didn't define it in your code

Comment: Sorry, now i added it to my question, it is defined in another class and is just a simple BoxLayout

Comment: still the same error AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: on_release:root.CreateTask(*args)
   File "MainScreen.py", line 26, in CreateTask
     self.ids.MainLayout.add_widget(bl)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: Mine works fine. Could you show me MainScreen.py?

Comment: updated it, now i wait till it will be approved

Comment: Now it shows nothing, maybe it's because MainScreenApp returns screenManager and kv file is not loaded for some reason

Comment: If you see different screens, I cannot help you. By the way, I used Kivy v2.0.0 and Python v3.6.9